# Using an external Groovy file with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I have two questions here regarding Jenkins pipeline and Groovy methods. Firstly I have multiple build that share common methods so thought best to have all these in a single class and then import the file for each build.

A snippet from my Groovy script looks like

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.Serializable;

Map get_var() {
      def gradleVars = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/gradle-client/gradle.properties"
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(gradleVars.getBytes());
      properties.load(is)

      def sdk_version = "SDKVersion"
      def SDK_VERSION = properties."$sdk_version"

    return [sdk_version: "$SDK_VERSION"}
}
```

And in my pipeline script I have

```
def groovyMethod = load("release_pipeline.groovy")
// Call method
groovyMethod.getVar()
```

The first problem I have is how do I use `${env.WORKSPACE}` within my method, and secondly how do I use `readFile` within my script as I get the error

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Helpers.readFile()

I am really new to Groovy and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the below :

```
def getVar() {
  def properties = new Properties()
  File propertiesFile = new File("${System.getenv['WORKSPACE']}/gradle-client/gradle.properties")
  properties.load(propertiesFile.newDataInputStream())


  return [sdk_version: properties.SDKVersion]

}
```

May be it appears that, you have different method name `get_var()` and you are trying to use `getVar()`.

And I am not really sure where that error coming from above script

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Helpers.readFile()

EDIT: based on OP comment

Please see if the this helps:

```
def workspace = Thread.currentThread().executable.workspace.toString()
```

Comment: Ahhh I've just realised what I've done with the method name.... silly error

Comment: Appreciate if it is accepted as answered if its helpful.

Comment: do you know how to access system vars as it doesnt seem to recognise `getenv`

Comment: @Richlewis, would you please check the EDIT part?

Comment: thanks, one last issue, `no such property it for class` any ideas ?

Comment: Which line of the script? `load(it)`?

Comment: Yes, that line. Thanks

Comment: Hey just replace the line with `properties.load(propertiesFile.newDataInputStream())`. Would you please try it?

Comment: just tried that, `sdk_version` is returned as null ?? hmmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145727/discussion-between-rao-and-richlewis).